# Existe diferença entre fofa e fofinha? Qual?

Tags: português-brasileiro

Eu vi que pessoas usam a palavra fofinha para falar sobre uma coisa que parece bonita.
Acho que é equivalente a **cute** em inglês.

E fofa?

> Eu vi **nuvem fofa**!

Pensava que fofa e fofinha tivessem o mesmo sentido. E procurando na Internet também parece assim. Mas neste exemplo parece outra coisa.

Uma explicação por favor!

Comment: Novamente, gosto muito das tuas perguntas... faz sempre eu pensar como um nativo usa a lingua e tudo mais. Essa pergunta em especifico, fez eu pensar na Interjeição *Bah*, usada no Rio Grande do Sul - Brasil, que tem mais de 200 significados dependendo do contexto e da entonação.

Comment: Is a fluffy cloud cute? ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**Fofo/a**](https://dicionario.priberam.org/fofo), tem um significado literal que segundo o priberam é:

> - adj. -  "que cede à pressão, mole. O oposto de duro, rijo.

Em Inglês poderia ser traduzido por **"soft"** ou **fluffy**.

Mas também pode ser usado, informalmente, em sentido figurado:

> - Que é bonito, meigo ou que suscita ternura ou afeto.

Neste caso, pode ser traduzido por **"cute"**, ou outras gírias com o mesmo sentido. Parece ser uma aquisição relativamente recente em pt-BR, de modo que não deve haver registro de seu uso em textos anteriores à segunda metade do século XX. (**opinião pessoal**)

Fofinho/a, é o diminutivo de fofo/a.  O uso mais comum é quando nos referimos a um bebê, um cãozinho, ou um filhote de outro animal.

- O bebê (a filha) da Lúcia é muito fofinho/a.
- Já viste a ninhada da minha gata?  São muito fofinhos.

De modo que a diferença entre *fofa* e *fofinha* é a mesma que entre *linda* e *lindinha*; a de uma palavra ser o diminutivo da outra.

Quanto à nuvem, "Eu vi uma nuvem fofa" provavelmente refere-se ao aspecto, e tem o sentido literal: uma núvem que parece um floco de algodão, macia.

O uso de fofo/a no diminutivo, precedido de *muito*, e com uma determinada inflexão de voz, tem uma grande probabilidade de a palavra estar sendo usada no sentido figurado.

Comment: Eu acho que o sentido figurado veio precisamente do sentido literal. Porque tudo que é *fofo* é *fofinho* também. Ou quase tudo vá. ;)

Comment: Querias dizer "um bebêzinho, um cãozinho, ou um filhotinho de outro animalzinho"? :-]

Comment: @ANeves  Não.  Eu quis dizer "um bebê, um cãozinho, ou um filhote de outro animal".

Comment: Uf, tão sério... quão profissional. :)

Answer (score 3):

O significado, apenas mudaria por estar no diminutivo, mas seria praticamente o mesmo. Mas temos que levar em conta que o diminutivo utilizado principalmente por brasileiros tem diferentes significados e precisa ser entendido pelo contexto.

> Contexto é tudo nessa dança linguística. Como meu novo amigo
>   brasileiro depois me explicou, usar "cervejinha" em vez de "cerveja"
>   implicava um convite inocente e amistoso, sem nenhuma intenção de se
>   embebedar até tarde da noite e tudo o que isso envolve. "Genial",
>   pensei. "Um sufixo pode dizer tudo isso?"

Mas a principio, tem o mesmo significado

> O linguista da Universidade de Brasília Marcos Bagno explica: "O
>   diminutivo em 'inho' e 'inha', além de indicar o tamanho pequeno de
>   algo, traz uma sensação de bondade e afeição - muito característicos
>   do espírito brasileiro".

Fonte: [F5-Você viu?](https://f5.folha.uol.com.br/voceviu/2019/01/por-que-o-brasileiro-ama-falar-no-diminutivo.shtml)